# Define rpart predictors with column index instead of name

Tags: r, decision-tree

I have the following line of code:

```
my_dt1 <- rpart(Survived ~ Pclass + Sex + Age + SibSp + Parch + Fare + Embarked, 
                  data = train2, 
                  method = "class")
```

I'd like to call those predictors (`Pclass`, `Sex`, `Age`, ...) with the corresponding column indexes in `train2` instead of the Column name to make the code more generalizable.

I tried changing `Pclass` for `train2[,3]`, but I get this error:

```
Error in data.frame(PassengerId = test2$PassengerId, Survived = my_prediction) :       arguments imply differing number of rows: 418, 891
In addition: Warning message:
'newdata' had 418 rows but variables found have 891 rows
```

Comment: How about `Vars = c(1,3,5,7) ; my_dt1 <- rpart(Survived ~ . , data = train2[ ,Vars])`  ?

Comment: @Dave2e Yes, I edited it

Comment: @G5W I wrote:`predictors <- c(3,5,6,7,8,10,12)   
  
  my_dt1 <- rpart(Survived ~ . ,
                    data = train2[, predictors], 
                    method = "class")` and I get this error: `Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Survived' not found`

Comment: The list of variables must include both the predictors and the variable to be predicted.  Supposing that Survived is variable number 15,  you could write something like ` rpart(Survived ~ . , data = train2[, c(predictors, 15)], method = "class")`

Comment: @G5W It's working now, thanks